# Server error with Apache, Gunicorn, and Django

Tags: django, apache, reverse-proxy, gunicorn

I am getting a server error with trying to reverse proxy to Gunicorn. 
My virtual host file looks like this:

`<virtualhost *:80>
    <Location /myApp>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass "http://127.0.0.1:8090/"
        ProxyPassReverse "http://127.0.0.1:8090/"
    </Location>
</virtualhost>`

And I'm running Gunicorn like this from within my Django project directory:

`gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8090 -w 3 myApp.wsgi`

Basically I'm wanting to reverse proxy requests to Gunicorn because I can't use mod_wsgi as it can't be compiled for the version of python I am running on my distro of Linux.

Comment: Why don't you use Ngnix instead of Apache? Ngnix is smooth for configuration. http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/

Comment: Company I work for uses Apache. I agree with you. I wish I could.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do     ProxyPass "/server" "http://127.0.0.1:8005/" to get this kind of thing to work it didn't like passing on the root /